# Emulate "Generate script" from SQL Server Management Studio with Pyodbc

Tags: python, database, ssms, pyodbc, sql-server-express

I'm trying to automate a backup process that my company is doing over a database managed with SQL Server Management Studio. The backup process involves regenerating a snapshot of a database, and so the first step is to use the "Generate scripts" option (in SSMS) over the database to obtain the SQL script that creates that database.

I've been told to use Pyodbc as part of the process, so I checked the docs but I haven't seen any function to get the generation script of a table directly. Is there a way to generate that script manually? What tables should I check to get the information a need to build the creation sentences?